# Get data from Firebase and assign

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am bit confused about assingning array of data to variable. I use code below to assing two data to firebase database:

```
pongo(adresa:string, chosen:boolean) {
  this.adresa = "sprite1.png"
  this.db.object(`/avatars/${this.userId}/`).set({avatar:this.adresa, chosen :false});
}
```

Than I grab that data with this code:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.db.list(`/avatars/${this.userId}`).valueChanges().subscribe(d => {
    this.avatar = d;
      });
  }
```

Now this gets me array of data with `avatar : sprite1.png` and `chosen :false`, but i want to access each data separate and assign state of chosen to `this.chosen = false` and  `this.avatar = "sprite1.png"`.

Anyone can clear up confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, the code I posted is ok. To access elements from array, I just had to use expression `{{avatar[0]}}` or `{{avatar[1]}}`. 
Hope this will help someone in future,

Cheers!